# When can a function be written as an evaluation rule?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, computer-science

In elementary Mathematics, one learns function as a rule for mapping elements $X \to Y$. For example, the rule for a function $f: R \to R$ could be written as:

$$ f(x) = x^2$$

But, as one learns higher mathematics, one learns function just a certain subset of $X \times Y$. Now, if it is just a subset, it may or may not be that the function has a rule to evaluate it element wise. **Is there any way to characterize if it does or not**? What type of restrictions are needed on the codomain and domain spaces such that all functions between are writable as an evaluation rule?

Comment: What counts as an evaluation rule? If $X$ is finite, can you give a lookup table?

Comment: yes, that'd work. The metamathematical intuition I can have is that the mapping over all the elements, can be written as some expression of finite length. For instance, f(x)=x^2 shows how uncountably many real numbers can be mapped but the expression in itself is less than 10 characters @Adam

Comment: It is not an arbitrary subset. It is a subset with a special property. If you want to see where $x$ is being mapped, then you look at your set and you will find a **unique** tuple $(x, y)$ whose first entry is the $x$ you started with. The corresponding $y$ is what we write as $f(x)$. So that's how the rule is encoded in the subset.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is finite and $Y$ is countable, then all functions $f: X \to Y$ are writable as evaluation rules, since we can express $f$ as a lookup table using finitely many symbols from a finite alphabet.

If $X$ is empty, or $Y$ has one element, then all functions $f$ are the same, so can easily be described.

If $X$ is infinite and $Y$ has at least two elements, or $X$ non-empty and $Y$ is uncountable, then there are uncountably many $f$, and only countably many expressions for $f$, so almost all functions $f$ are inexpressible.

Given a specific $f$, asking whether it can be expressed will depend on your choice of symbol language.

Comment: my symbol language...?

Comment: Your definition of what an "evaluation rule" is. @TrystwithFreedom